# Cordova + Win10 + WebSocket: connection fails with SECURITY_ERR

Tags: windows, cordova, win-universal-app

I'm porting an existing Cordova app from Android to Windows 10. The app must open a WebSocket connection to a remote server. At the moment, the connection always fails with the error "WebSocket Error: SECURITY_ERR, Cross zone connection not allowed". The same app is also making regular AJAX requests to the same server and they're working fine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and testing the app locally, using Edge/13.10586.

Is it possible to make the WebSocket connection to work?

**UPDATE**

My app has both "Internet (Client)" and "Private Networks (Client & Server)" capabilities set. Further tests show that the problem is caused by the combination of web context ("ms-appx-web:") and attempting to connect the WebSocket to a non-FQDN (I'm using only the hostname). If I use FQDN or the IP address instead, it works. If I use local context ("ms-appx:") instead, with non-FQDN, it works.

Comment: UWP applications have restrictions with access to network. Have you tried to add Internet (Client & Server), Internet (Client) and Private Networks (Client & Server) capabilities in the "Package.appxmanifest"?

Comment: I didn't really find a solution. The combination ms-appx-web:// + Private Networks (Client & Server) + non-FQDN websocket still does not work. In that scenario, does the websocket server need to use Access-Control-Allow-Origin header during the handshaking process?

Comment: Where is your server side app localized? "ms-appx" means inside your app package. I don't see any option to use it for a remote connection. You can refer to [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.uri) for details.

Comment: It''s a Cordova app. It's local to the application. But it connects to a remote server through AJAX requests and WebSocket.